# Nvidia Card isn't working, only detecting onboard card

Tags: graphics-card

I can't seem to get my video card to work. I don't exactly know what Nvidia model it is because it's an old card that my cousin gave me.

I plugged in my monitor to the VGA but nothing shows up, no signal but when I plug it into the motherboard's monitor slot everything works out fine.

I went from a 9800GT since there is something wrong with it, but now I'm not so sure if it's the motherboard or if my card is the problem.

In Device Manager there is only my onboard card (ATI Radeon 3200 HD) and no Nvidia device.

Comment: More information please. What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using a Windows Vista 64 bit OS

Answer (score 1):

1) Have you verified that the card is working?
2) Is there an option to disable the onboard GPU in your BIOS?  Have you verified this setting since removing your 9800GT?
3) Have you verified that your motherboard detects the new videocard?  Does Windows detect it?

Answer (score 0):

Does the card need extra power? A lot of higher spec cards require more power than they can get through the motherboard slot so have an connector - usually on the top corner of the card.